# How do I put a GLSL script into an `htmlDependency()`?

Tags: r, r-markdown, htmltools

The `htmltools::htmlDependency` function allows me to set Javascript and CSS files as a dependency of a tag.  This means I can have tags on a page that use the code without including multiple copies of it, and in `rmarkdown`, if I set `self_contained: false`, I don't include any copies of the files in the HTML, just references to external copies.

Now I'd like to have a GLSL shader program as part of the dependency as well.

I can insert something like `<script type="text/plain" id="shader"> ... shader code </script>` as the `head` argument to `htmlDependency()`, and that inserts the shader into the header section of the page, but `self_contained: false` makes no difference:  I always get a copy there.

Is there a way to get `htmlDependency` to treat a `text/plain` script the way it treats the Javascript scripts?

Here's an example in an RMarkdown document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
---

```{r}
javascript <- 'console.log("this is Javascript to write to the console");'
f1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".js")
writeLines(javascript, f1)

text <- 'this is some text to go in a script'
f2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")
writeLines(text, f2)
```

```{r}
library(htmltools)
deps <- htmlDependency("test", "1.0",
                       src = tempdir(),
                       script = basename(f1),
                       head = as.character(includeScript(f2,
                                                         type = "text/plain",
                                                         id = "shader")))
tag <- tags$p("this is visible text", deps)
tag
```
````

If you process that and look at the generated HTML page, you'll see something like this in the header after a lot of code to load other scripts:

```
<script src="Untitled_files/test-1.0/file60301b7b90b0.js"></script>
<script type="text/plain" id="shader">this is some text to go in a script</script>
```

The first line loads the Javascript to write to the console, and the second line
contains the script that I didn't want to include in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's not so hard.  The `script` argument to `htmlDependency()` can take a mixture of filenames and more complicated things.  To get what I wanted, I would use

```
deps <- htmlDependency("test", "1.0",
                       src = tempdir(),
                       script = list(basename(f1),
                                     list(src = basename(f2),
                                          type = "text/plain",
                                          id = "shader")))
```

The second item in the `script` argument contains the attributes for the `<script>` tag that will be inserted.

EDITED to add:  I want to point out two things:

1. There's a bug in `htmltools` version 0.5.2 which can cause this to fail.  [This PR](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/pull/321) should fix it.
2. My original goal of using this to share GLSL shaders between pages isn't going to be met:  it's not easy for the code on the page to read the content of the `text/plain` external script.  (I'd love for someone to contradict this!)